Scattered objects using partcile system, ends up outside the plane, possible keep it within the plane?
I'm working on a project where I'm trying to position various objects on a plane using a particle system. (see pictures)
The problem is that the object ends up outside the shape, and I'm wondering if there's a way to keep it within the plane?
The file:



Vertex Groups > Density



What about painting a vertex group and using it under Vertex Groups > Density so that the particles are only generated within its limits?

Good idea, I tried that but it still get cubes outside the shape. (I'll upload it in the post)

See my answer, you need to leave enough margin

Paint a vertex group in Weight Paint, make sure that you have enough margin:

Select this group under Vertex Groups > Density:

